# How to determine if SmartLock is enabled on device

Tags: google-api, google-smartlockpasswords

It's possible to disable "Smart Lock for Passwords" in the Google settings, so my app shouldn't show the login hints, if it's disabled on the system layer.

Is there anything equivalent to determine if Smart Lock is disabled, like the API to check if Google Play Services is available `GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance()                                                       .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this))`?

Comment: If you call the API and Smart Lock is disabled for all accounts, you should get a callback result with status "CANCELED", "NO_ELIGIBLE_ACCOUNTS", with message "No eligible accounts can be found". Try it out and see if that is the case?

Comment: Well, that solved half of my problem, because now it's possible to avoid retrieving the credentials, but it still let me retrieve the sign in hints. There is no callback where I can avoid calling `Auth.CredentialsApi.getHintPickerIntent()` when disabled.

Comment: But the hints are still useful for auto-fill, even if the API to save / retreive credentials is not available?

Comment: But it would be nice to turn it somehow off, especially when there are no hints available and there is only a blank dialog with the dismiss button.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce a blank dialog with only the dismiss button (can you attach a screenshot)? There should be no intent to resolve in that case, if you're getting it, then it's actually a bug :/  Thanks!

Comment: I've added the screenshot in a separate answer.

Comment: Thanks this is a bug and should not be happening, I'll escalate to the engineering team. Thank you for reporting!

Comment: @StevenSoneff please let me know which API gives the status as cancelled if smart lock is disabled from settings of the device

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug if empty picker is returned; it should not be happening. Have escalated to engineering team and fix is pending. Affects less than <1% of live devices. Will update this answer when the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

[image: No hints available]

I'm getting this dialog, if no hints are available, so I can only dismiss this dialog.