# How to determine programmatically if SmartLock is disabled on device

Tags: android, google-smartlockpasswords

I want to determine if a user has disabled the smart lock from settings option of device.I have also read the [How to determine if SmartLock is enabled on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36402251/how-to-determine-if-smartlock-is-enabled-on-device) it says API will return a callback with status cancelled but I am not able to determine which API will do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18720287/5272951

Comment: I suppose the link above indicates whether a pin or pattern is set on a device and not the google smart lock for passwords.

Comment: I am facing some issue in password sync. can you please have a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63830860/app-and-website-saved-password-is-not-sync

Answer (score 1):

The problem faced was the Smart Lock for Passwords was disabled for single account and CredentialRequest API thus returned successful callback. You need to disable for all accounts in your device settings and then smart lock functionality will not work. Hope it will be helpful for someone.

Comment: Can you please share a code snippet for this? I just want to check if SmartLock is enabled or not, think this might help

Comment: I am facing some issue in password sync. can you please have a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63830860/app-and-website-saved-password-is-not-sync